# Setting user name for Request event?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have implemented a custom authentication scheme in a web service based on the ASP.NET Core webhost. I want to add Application Insights to this service.

When I successfully authenticate the user, I do something like this

```
telemetry.Context.User.Id = authenticatedUserName;
```

the `telemetry` object is the `TelemetryClient` I get from dependency injection.

Now, the problem is that the user ID does not show up among the requests, and I am not sure why.

This works

```
customEvents | where user_Id != "" and name  == "MyCustomEvent"
```

but not this

```
request | where user_Id != ""
```

or this

```
dependencies | where user_Id != ""
```

Is there somewhere else where I should set the user ID for the request? I'd rather not create a custom event just for this.

I also tried setting the `User` property on the `HttpContext` object, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer was surprisingly simple.

```
HttpContext ctx = ...
var requestTelemetry = ctx.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>()

requestTelemetry.Context.User.Id = authenticationResult.UserName;
```

Comment: Please mark one of them as answer, it would be helpful for others.

Comment: Not allowed to yet :)

Answer (score 6):

You should use [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer) for your purpose.

The following is my test steps(asp.net core 2.1):

Step 1:Add the `Aplication Insights telemetry` by `right click your project -> Add -> Application Insights telemetry`. The screenshot as below:
[image]

Step 2:Add a new class which implements the ITelemetryInitializer:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace WebApplication33netcore
{
    public class MyTelemetryInitializer: ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var request = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
            if (request != null)
            {
                //set the user id here with your custom value
                request.Context.User.Id = "ivan111";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Step 3:Register your telemetry initializer in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs. For details, refer to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration):

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
         {

          options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
          options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
         });


         services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

         //Add the following code to register your telemetry initializer
         services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>(new MyTelemetryInitializer());
    }
```

Step 4:Check the test result:

In visual studio Application Insights Search:
[image]

Then check it in Analytics:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But when is the Initialize method run? Can I be sure that my authentication logic has been run? Though maybe I could use the initializer to save away the RequestTelemetry object otherwise.

Comment: Following that route I think I found an easy solution. I’ll document my findings once I’ve verified it.